# getting specific values from objects within arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

Considering the following array which includes several objects within it, I tried to get specific values in one single array.To put it delicately,I wanted to pull out the name of people who were in the "red" team.

```
// 
    const array = [
      {
        username: "Mike",
        team: "red",
        score: 20,
     items: ["bat", "book", "gloves"]
  },
  {
    username: "Moe",
    team: "blue",
    score: 30,
    items: ["cellphone", "backpack", "cards"]
  },
  {
    username: "Ellie",
    team: "red",
    score: 15,
    items: ["ball", "canteen", "crayon"]
  },
  {
    username: "little_joe",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pencil"]
  },

];

//using filter method :

const filterArray=array.filter((num)=>{ if (num.team==="red" ){ return num.username}});
console.log(filterArray);

//result : an array including two objects full of unwanted values.
```

---

What should I do to get one single array with only desired value ( not two big objects) ?

I'm trying to get an array like this :
(2)►[Mike,Ellie]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.map`. However, **the preferred** way would be to use `Array.prototype.reduce` as it will be much more efficient.

Like this:

```js
const array = [{
    username: "Mike",
    team: "red",
    score: 20,
    items: ["bat", "book", "gloves"]
  },
  {
    username: "Moe",
    team: "blue",
    score: 30,
    items: ["cellphone", "backpack", "cards"]
  },
  {
    username: "Ellie",
    team: "red",
    score: 15,
    items: ["ball", "canteen", "crayon"]
  },
  {
    username: "little_joe",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pencil"]
  },

];

const newArray = array.reduce((n, val) => {
  if(val.team == "red") n.push(val.username);
  return n;
}, []);

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: it's fine, but why this gimmick usage of ternary operator `val.team == "red" ? n.push(val.username) : null;` instead of straightforward `if(val.team == "red") n.push(val.username);` ?

Comment: @jedzej you're right. I shouldn't be using ternary for ternary's sake. Answer updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` doesn't return the values that were returned by the callback, it just checks if it's truthy, and uses that to decide whether to return the array element.

You can do it in two steps. First use `filter` to get just the elements with `team === "red"`, then use `map` to extract `username`:

```
const filterArray = array.filter(num => num.team === "red").map(num => num.username);
```

You can also do it in one step using `reduce`, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Barmar, here's a version using `reduce`:

```
const redTeamPeople = array.reduce((people, { team, username }) => {
  if (team === "red") {
    people.push(username);
  }

  return people;
}, []);
```

Comment: This is the preferred method. More concise and much faster given a very large array with a lot of data.